# Vue router - Multiple router-views and nested paths

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

*Disclaimer: I've searched many sites and tried out multiple things from documentation, but i'm just not getting it correctly. Please do not downvote just because of that, thanks.*

I'm making an app where i'd like to use multiple name `router-views` so that i can render some compontents into them. I was hoping to come to the point where i can define some components for named router-views in the parent route and add some more (or overwrite them) in children routes, f.e:

```
{
  path: '/'
  components: {
    content: componentA,
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'somePath',
      components: {
        toolbar: componentB
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in the *somePath*, only thing that's rendered would be *componentB* within toolbar *routerView*.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to somehow "extend" the components set from children routes?
2. Am i correct, that the `router-views` can only be siblings? You can't nest them? Or is nesting router-views a way to achieve what i'm trying to do? Please provide some link if that's the case, couldn't find anything enough explanatory.

Comment: You can nest `router-view` see what I did here. https://github.com/jofftiquez/open-todo

Comment: @CENT1PEDE I finally had some time to look back into that. Your example was really helpful. I've got no clue what did i do wrong, but i've managed to extract minimal example as codePen and it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @entio Im glad it help you.